# ActionListener and ChangeListener changing the paintComponent doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, graphics, listener, jcomponent

The user suppose to type in a string to change the text printed & change the slider to change the size of the circle. But neither the slider and the textfield have any responses.

The components (slider, textfield, string, circle) all printed out but it just didn't respond to anything

paintComponent

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawString(text,100,10);
    g.fillOval(100,100,circleSize,circleSize);
}
```

TextField

```
class TextfieldPanel extends JPanel
{
    public TextfieldPanel()
    {
        TextfieldHandler thandler = new TextfieldHandler();
        textfield = new JTextField("enter",10);
        add(textfield);
        textfield.addActionListener(thandler);
    }

    class TextfieldHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {
            String input = textfield.getText();
            text = input;
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Slider

```
class SliderPanel extends JPanel
{
    public SliderPanel()
    {
        SliderHandler shandler = new SliderHandler();
        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL);
        add(slider);
        slider.addChangeListener(shandler);
    }

    class SliderHandler implements ChangeListener
    {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt)
        {
            int value = slider.getValue();
            circleSize = value;
            repaint();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: The the slider panel and text field panel have any concept of the circle panel, so they are simple not capable of affecting it in any meaningful way.  Wha you need is a common model which can be shared between the three and which can generate state change events, so the circle panel can update itself when there is a change to the model.  The "basic concept" you're looking for is an "observer pattern".

Comment: @MadProgrammer so what part of the code should I change?

Comment: It would be good to have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And instead of trying to accomplish two things at once (string & circle), try only one thing 1st. Your question a code is then simpler and it'll be easier to help.

Comment: @StaceyLee Well, all of it. You need to define a "model" which holds the data, which is shared between the classes. You need to determine "how" the listeners are notified when the state changes and you need to change your "paint" code so that it uses the model data

Comment: Now I found out that if I hide the window and open again, the circle did changed its size. But what I want is that as I adjust the slider the circle size will change right away. How can I achieve that?